# Scroll doesnt work in chrome for hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am facing this issue in chrome. What I have done is

A button on hover shows a div. The div has the scroll bar but on mouseover on scroll hides the div. I am not sure whats the problem but it seems to be working fine in firefox, IE11 and Edge. It doesnt work in Opera and Chrome.
Please see below for better understanding.

```css
#container {
  display:none;
  width:100%;  
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
}
#parent:hover #container {
  display: block;
}
body {
  overflow:auto;
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button>
  test
  </button>

  <div id="container">
        <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you try to scroll inside the div, the div becomes hidden?

Comment: I think he means that as soon as you hover over the scrollbar inside the container, the container hides.

Comment: Thanks Jao. Your correct

Comment: Are you using mac?

Comment: No I am using windows machine

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of it getting hidden by the OS.

Override this with css.

```
#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

#container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Try this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/Eh7xT/1130/

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want container position absolute,

```css
#container {
  display:none;
  width:100%;  
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  right:0;
}
#parent:hover #container {
  display: block;
}
body {
  overflow:auto;
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button>
  test
  </button>

  <div id="container">
        <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
      <div> 
        some content
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ose I need position to be absolute and it doesn't  work even after changing to relative